# Make entire site in fit the middle using media queries and jQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, media-queries

Hi i am new to jquerymobile .i am developing a site using jquerymobile and phonegap, i am able to make it for the mobile device but i am facing hard time making my site look good on browser. 
I want my complete site to be centered ,but my header and footer seems to have a problem , there is gap on top for header and gap at bottom for footer iam doing as below.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px){
    .ui-page {
     width: 560px !important;
     margin: 0 auto !important;
     position: relative !important;
     border-right: 5px #666 outset !important;
     border-left: 5px #666 outset !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px){

    .ui-header,.ui-footer {
     width: 560px !important;
     margin: 0 auto !important;
     position: relative !important;

    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

As u can see from pics there are gaps on top of header and bottom of footer.
need to remove those gaps and i need suggestions on different pixel sizes for best viewing.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: i partially solved it by removing data-position=fixed attribute but i want only content to scroll and with fixed header and footer

Answer (score 0):

For the header and footer, you can set the width to 560px, then set the left position to 50%, then give it a negative left margin equal to half the width (-280px):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    .ui-page {
        width: 560px !important;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
        position: relative !important;
        border-right: 5px #666 outset !important;
        border-left: 5px #666 outset !important;
    }
    .ui-header-fixed, .ui-footer-fixed {
        width: 560px !important;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -280px;
    }
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/y5kNb/1/)**